# Azure tags: search for value including wildcard

Tags: azure, azure-cli

We'd like to have multi-valued tags. For example, for the tag "application", we have some resources that involve several applications, i.e. Virtual Machines running several JBoss instances for different applications. As far as I know, multi-valued tags are not allowed for the time being. As a workaround, I'm considering values for the tag like "app1, app2". However, I can't see how we could actually use those values for proper queries. I would have expected to be able to do something like

```
az resource list --tag 'application=*app1*'
```

That's not working though. According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list, wildcards are allowed in tag names, but not in tag values:

```
az resource list --tag 'test*'
```

Are you aware of any method we could use to handle these pseudo-multi-valued tags?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

The filter in the Az CLI will not allow that kind of search, so you would have to do that sort of filtering yourself in your own bash/PowerShell code once you retrieve a list of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Does not work also on the web interface.

It was a feature candidate, but was abandoned by Microsoft.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-query-off-of-wildcards/418475#T-N419130